# Cancelling external event handler raised inside task

Tags: c#

Quick question, I'm running a task that's raising an event which some other object is subscribing to. Is there a way to cancel that object's event handler mid-execution? Attempted to do that using cancellation tokens,

```
                    public event Action<Int> OnUpdate;

                    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(state => {
                        try {
                            var token = (CancellationToken)state;
                            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                            OnUpdate(_int);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Console.WriteLine("Update threw exception : {0}", e.Message);
                        }
                    }, cts.Token, cts.Token);

                    if (!t.Wait(8000, cts.Token)) {
                        cts.Cancel();
                        Console.WriteLine("Update task did not finish in time.");
                    } else {
                        Console.WriteLine("Task did finish in time.");
                    }
```

The idea here is I'm starting a new task, t, which raises an event, OnUpdate, which is caught and handled by an external object. I want the task to cancel if it's taking more than 8 seconds to handle the update which was the idea behind the cancellation token usage. However, even if I call cts.Cancel(), the external event handler still runs to completion. Is there anything I can do?

Edit - for clarity as a commenter pointed out, I'm stuck with using Action here as this is a public-facing API I'm editing. I could potentially move to spawning new Threads instead of tasks and then calling Thread.Abort() but that seems rather brutish; I would prefer a much nicer solution.

Comment: As an aside, when using `event` it's good practice to follow the `EventHandler` pattern: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I agree, but this code is coming from a public API I'm modifying and can't change from the Actions to EventHandlers while preserving backwards compatibility.

Comment: `CancellationToken`s can only be checked when you have control.  It's voluntary, so it's much more effective in loops.  If your event handler is not returning in time there's nothing a Task can do to stop it.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I figured that was the case. Guess I'll change the task out to a Thread and just abort when its taking too long. If you repost that comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct, at least within the scope of my original question.

Comment: You may want to check this out: http://binary-studio.com/2015/10/23/task-cancellation-in-c-and-things-you-should-know-about-it/

Comment: It still doesn't solve the voluntary check issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, a `CancellationToken` can only do it's job when it is actually observed.  On the plus side, this allows you to ensure your application can clean up it's state before returning early from a task.  However, it requires the code in the task to actively interact with the `CancellationToken`.

In the case where you want to terminate an event handler that's completely out of your control, you don't have enough granularity to force the check after a period of time.

**Important:** If you are using Task Asynchronous Protocol (TAP), never call `Task.Wait()`.  That is a blocking call that prevents your application from doing anything.  You might as well just call the handler directly and avoid the headache.  If you didn't care how long the callback takes and you simply want to do something after it's done, then the proper technique is to use `async`/`await`.  In that case the solution would change to something like this:

```
public Task async NotifyUpdate(int value)
{
    await Task.Run(() => OnUpdate(value));

    // Continue with your post update code here
    // nothing blocked at all.
}
```